# Setting value in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a AutoCompleteTextView with a list of items, and I need select one of them...

I am doing something like:

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setListSelection( index);
```

and...

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setText( index);
```

but don't work... How can I set a item by default?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will not work because `setText` takes a `CharSequence`.

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(index);
```

> public final void setText (CharSequence text)

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

If you have a data structure such as a `List<String> data`, you can do something like this:

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(data.get(index));
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: Thanks Jared!! One hour in front of my eyes and I couldn't see it!!

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Legendary

Comment: When I do this, I only have a single item in my dropdown menu, any solution?
`binding.prioritySpinner.setText(getItem(1), false)`

Answer (score 8):

`setText(CharSequence text, boolean filter)` if you don't want filter. You can make it `false`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(adapter.getItem(2),false);
      }
```

Comment: myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(adapter.getItem(index)) default comes with filter option. that means in dropdown list only show the similar item as index value . if you want to show entire list in dropdown you need to make filter false eg: myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(adapter.getItem(index) , false)

Comment: I went up and down to check why my autocomplete not showing the list and only showing one item after settext(index). now I know, I need to set filter to false. Thans!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value of AutoCompleteTextView using following ways:

1. Using **position** or **index**

   `myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(adapter.getItem(1),false);`
2. Using the **value** or **string**

   `myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(value,false);`
3. If you want to do the **filter** also, then remove the false.

   `myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(value);`